# Change icon on mel script on shelf using mel or python

Tags: python, mel, maya-api

I have used the addNewShelfTab and scriptToShelf command in MEL to create an icon for my mini mel script. I want to be able to change the icon for this button from the default like you can from the Shelf Editor by using either MEL or Python. How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

[shelfButton mel command help](http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/Commands/shelfButton.html#flagimage)

```
shelfButton -edit -image1 "icon.png" $name;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following python script worked for me:

```
import maya.mel as mel
import pymel.core as pm

mel.eval('addNewShelfTab($shelfName)');
pm.shelfButton( annotation='Annotation', image1=$image, command='<command>' );
```